# Formatting input field phone number with EventListener keyup

Tags: javascript, regex, forms

I'm working on a form where I need the phone number field to reformat, as you type, into
*xxx-xxx xx xx*.
This in itself is straight forward and has been asked before but my problem is a bit different:

I've used the JavaScript only approach found in **[this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rafj3md0/)**, but to adjust to my wanted format I've edited the last code block into this:

```
const areacode = input.substring(0,3);
const gr1 = input.substring(3,6);
const gr2 = input.substring(6,8);
const gr3 = input.substring(8,10);

if(input.length > 7) {
      target.value = `${areacode}-${gr1} ${gr2} ${gr3}`;
    } else if(input.length > 5) {
      target.value = `${areacode}-${gr1} ${gr2}`;
    } else if(input.length > 2) {
      target.value = `${areacode}-${gr1}`;
    } else if(input.length > 0) {
      target.value = `${areacode}`;
    }
```

When I try this out in the fiddle, or paste in codepen for example, it works perfectly. But when I apply it to my site, it doesn't. The characters are replaced in a weird manner.

---

Suspicion: There's a constant containing a regex replace, like so:

```
const input = event.target.value.replace(/\D/g,'').substring(0,10);
```

I'm not good with RegEx but as this works in one place but not the other I feel I have to suspect this line of code.

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Experimenting with the code you provided in the question, I found that it works correctly indeed. Please don't post working code on StackOverflow asking what is wrong with it.

Nevertheless, I examined your website with a debugger and found an issue with the regex: Instead of using `input.replace(/\D/g, "")`, you wrote `input.replace(/D/g, "")`, which removes all `D` characters.

As a side note, I can highly recommend setting breakpoints in the browser source view to solve such problems.

Comment: FYI, I had to edit the question to try to generalize it a bit, as the url to the site in question is temporary and no longer working.